# .Net Core 2.0 IIS Windows Authentication Issue

Tags: c#, .net, iis, .net-core, windows-authentication

I have developed a simple web application in .Net Core 2.0

I haven't run into any issues until I have deployed the site in IIS. The application uses Windows Authentication, which by and large is working absolutely fine. I have allowed all domain users and the generated web.config file looks like this (security section):

```
<security>
<authorization>
<remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
<add accessType="Allow" roles="AD\Domain Users" />
</authorization>
</security>
```

For some domain users, this is not working. They get prompted with a browser based login request and are subsequently denied access. I can't understand why this is happening for some users but not others.

The website is on port 80, which is open to all subnets, so technically all domain users should be able to access the web application.

Can anyone advise what might be the issue here? I'm scratching my head a little bit. I don't know if this is related to my configuration, IIS, or the web config, or maybe something to do with .Net core.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What browser are they using?

Comment: Tried on both chrome and Ie 11

Comment: Chrome doesn't support Windows auth.

Comment: "They get prompted with a browser based login request and are subsequently denied access" Did they enter their domain credentials? Including the domain? e.g. DOMAINNAME\userName

Comment: Chrome is authenticating me and many other users in fine though

Comment: What does the Security event log say about these logins? It should give the reason for failure.

Comment: Yes they have entered the credentials correctly, ie domain\username

Comment: Then you should really look how to enable automatic NTLM responses for those particular browsers. In Firefox there are some options for that in `about:config`, e.g. `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris`.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in the IIS logs or even viewer security logs. Is there anywhere else worth checking?